# Unable to get Firebase messaging token in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a chrome extension that receives push notifications.  This has worked with previous versions of firebase (4.4.0), but following the recent upgrade to 5.2.0 I am no longer able to get the token.  Note that I cleared some caches and made a few additional changes during this upgrade, so it may have nothing to do with the new FB version.

As you can see from the code and output below, when I execute the getToken() promise, it never invokes the "then" or "catch" handlers.  I don't see any messages in the console, network tab, or anything else that indicate anything is happening at all.  Any ideas?

- Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- MAC 10.12.6

Code in my extension's background.js:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
var fbmessaging = firebase.messaging();

function getToken(){

    trace('Getting new token');
    var promise = fbmessaging.getToken();

    trace('Have getToken() promise.  Executing.');
    promise.then(function(newToken) {
        trace('New token received: ' +newToken);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        trace('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
    });
}

fbmessaging.requestPermission()
.then(function() {
    trace('Notification permission granted.');
    getToken();
}).catch(function(err) {
    trace('Unable to get firebase messaging permission: ' +err);
});

fbmessaging.onTokenRefresh(function(arg) {
    trace("OnTokenRefresh called. " +arg);
    getToken();
});
```

Complete output from trace:

```
Notification permission granted.
Getting new token
Have getToken() promise.  Executing.
```

Comment: I have been able to determine that, despite receiving a response from requestPermission() that permission has been granted, an issue remains.  If I manually add my extension's ID to my notifications "allowed" list in chrome settings, then getToken() returns normally.

Comment: I have tried removing "gcm" and "notifications" permissions from my manifest to see if I could trigger a notifications approval prompt, but I am never prompted.  I have investigated/tested other approaches such as registering push notifications & a service worker from a "real" website, but since chrome.runtime is not available in the service worker there is no way to get the message over to my extension.  Any way I can get a notification to my extension?